# Pyspark window over last days and last rows

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to collect the history of rows in a new column based on two conditions:

- the previous rows should be included only if they are not older than 10 days from the current row, and
- not more than the last 2 rows should be included

The input data looks as follows:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2023-05-02 | 300 |
| 1 | 2023-05-03 | 400 |
| 1 | 2023-05-04 | 500 |
| 2 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

and the result I would like to achieve with the added column:

| id | date | value | history |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 100 | () |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 200 | () |
| 1 | 2023-05-02 | 300 | (1, 2023-05-01, 200) |
| 1 | 2023-05-03 | 400 | (1, 2023-05-01, 200), (1, 2023-05-02, 300) |
| 1 | 2023-05-04 | 500 | (1, 2023-05-02, 300), (1, 2023-05-03, 400) |
| 2 | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The window below takes the previous two rows, but I would like to add the maximum time difference in this window as well.

```
window = Window.orderBy('date').partitionBy('id').rowsBetween(-3, -1)
```

Who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, datetime(2023, 1, 1), 100),
    (1, datetime(2023, 5, 1), 200),
    (1, datetime(2023, 5, 2), 300),
    (1, datetime(2023, 5, 3), 400),
    (1, datetime(2023, 5, 4), 500)
], ['id', 'date', 'value'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('content_struct', f.struct('id', 'date', 'value'))
    .withColumn('history', f.collect_list(f.col('content_struct')).over(Window.orderBy('date').partitionBy('id').rowsBetween(-3, -1)))
    .withColumn('history', f.expr('filter(history, x -> x.date >= (date - interval 2 day))'))
)

df.show(truncate = False)
```

and the output is:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |date               |value|content_struct               |history                                                       |
+---+-------------------+-----+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |2023-01-01 00:00:00|100  |{1, 2023-01-01 00:00:00, 100}|[]                                                            |
|1  |2023-05-01 00:00:00|200  |{1, 2023-05-01 00:00:00, 200}|[]                                                            |
|1  |2023-05-02 00:00:00|300  |{1, 2023-05-02 00:00:00, 300}|[{1, 2023-05-01 00:00:00, 200}]                               |
|1  |2023-05-03 00:00:00|400  |{1, 2023-05-03 00:00:00, 400}|[{1, 2023-05-01 00:00:00, 200}, {1, 2023-05-02 00:00:00, 300}]|
|1  |2023-05-04 00:00:00|500  |{1, 2023-05-04 00:00:00, 500}|[{1, 2023-05-02 00:00:00, 300}, {1, 2023-05-03 00:00:00, 400}]|
+---+-------------------+-----+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I was looking for a way to apply the two filters within the window operation, but this also works indeed